# Cannot Reference UserControl from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have added a Web User Control called HomePageItem to my project and I am trying to create a new instance of it in from a page called LandingPage.aspx programatically. For some reason the class is not visible. I just get an build error that says:

The type or namespace name 'Controls_HomePageItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the line of code in my LandingPage.aspx file:

```
Controls_HomePageItem hpi = new Controls_HomePageItem();
```

And here is the entire HomePageItem.ascx file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Controls_HomePageItem : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried putting the control in a namespace called HomePage
like so:

```
namespace HomePage {
    public partial class Controls_HomePageItem : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  

        }
    }
}
```

And then referencing the Control like so in LandingPage.aspx
    HomePage.Controls_HomePageItem hpi = new HomePage.Controls_HomePageItem();

and I tried a using statement at the top:

```
using HomePage;
```

Same issues still. I cant even see the HomePage namespace from LandingPage.aspx

Please help.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I solved it. When I add Register of my usercontrol to aspx file then I can reference usercontrol class in code. I create my usercontrol only from code, but Register is needed.

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a namespace line in there?

between the using and the public partial class, there should be a namespace line.

Comment: Thats how the file was created by VS2008. But I'll try inserting it manually quick.

Comment: @Muhammad: I want to programmaticaly create an instance of the usercontrol in one of my pages, but cannot see the class. And yeah, its in my page's code behind, the .cs file, not the aspx file.

Comment: Is your projects name space then "Homepage"?

Comment: The project is in the default namespace. I can see some of the other controls that are also in the default namespace. Just not any new ones that I create. It's as if Visual Studio is broken.

Comment: It just sounds like the name space for all your times is different and you have some in one, and some in another.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue.
The project was created as a website and not a Web Application. Visual studio continually builds new controls in the background, but there was an issue with my build because some of the referenced DLLs were checked out exclusively out of source control by someone else. The website would still build and run and such, but none of the control classes were being generated. As soon as I sorted out the source control issue with the checked out DLLs, my controls started building normally.

Thank you for everyones responses.